# Doxywizard next button is disabled

Tags: doxygen, doxygen-wizard

I have installed Doxygen 1.8.7 on my Windows 7 pc. Downloaded a sample project from [here](https://github.com/GarageGames/Torqeue2D) 
Started the Doxywizard filled the values on all the tabs (Project, Mode, Output, Diagram) but after completing all this the next button is still disabled.

find the screen shots bellow

[image: Project]
[image: Mode]
[image: Output]
[image: Diagrams]

what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think you are talking about the next button on the Diagrams page. This is the last page of Topics tab so there is no next here (Similar to the Previous button on the Project page). The Next step would be to go to the run tab (or expert tab).

Comment: See also [superuser: DoxyWizrad "run" button is not enabled](https://superuser.com/questions/1757760/doxywizrad-run-button-is-not-enabled/1833286).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @albert said this is the last thing in Wizard tab. Select Run tab and click start doxygen and you are done. Sometimes doxygen may stop instantly this is because your Aniti Virus may block the application in such case add doxygen to exception or something like that in your AV.

Comment: See also [superuser: DoxyWizrad "run" button is not enabled](https://superuser.com/questions/1757760/doxywizrad-run-button-is-not-enabled/1833286).

Answer (score 15):

Pardon me while I resurrect this dead post, but I arrived here by researching the same problem as the OP.

It turns out we have different problems, but others may search as I have, and end up here.

In my case, although the NEXT button was indeed grayed out, I also had the problem where the "Run Doxygen" button was grayed out.

In my case, the reason the "Run Doxygen" button was grayed out was that I had chosen an output directory that was in a folder I did not have write-access to. (C:\Project_html).

I was able to resolve my situation by re-launching Doxygen with admin privileges.

Comment: Thanks for you tips, and also note that if the output path is not created yet, the "Run Doxygen" will be grayed out too.

Comment: 20190527 I too had the "Run Doxygen" button grayed out and I too closed and found I could get the "Run Doxygen" working after running in administrator mode

Comment: Wow thanks for that nugget. Fixed my problem!

Comment: See also [superuser: DoxyWizrad "run" button is not enabled](https://superuser.com/questions/1757760/doxywizrad-run-button-is-not-enabled/1833286).

Answer (score 2):

For me "**Run doxygen**" button was disabled. After checking all the configuration options i found that the directory which it was expecting at "**Step 1: Specify the working directory from which doxygen will run**" was the directory where **doxygen.exe** was located. So in my case it was "**C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin**"

Comment: This is not the intention of "Step 1: Specify the working directory from which doxygen will run". The doxygen executable should be available parallel to the doxywizard (or in the path). The "Step 1: Specify the working directory from which doxygen will run" is intended to specify where the program should run so the relative path (like in `INPUT`, `OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`,  etc.) will be resolved and the output comes at the right place. When specifying the place of the doxygen executable all other directories should be relative to this directory or be absolute paths.

Comment: See also [superuser: DoxyWizrad "run" button is not enabled](https://superuser.com/questions/1757760/doxywizrad-run-button-is-not-enabled/1833286).

Answer (score 1):

Although indeed not an error, I agree this can be a bit confusing. I've just pushed a change to GitHub that makes the Next button jump to the Run tab (which is typically the next logical step to take).

See the commit here:
https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/commit/fbc60af2298c2668893e2f7045f66765f8e0c63f